# Getting higher stream number for lower order stream in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, watershed, stream-order, basin

[image: the fourth order stream is showing greater strem number then third]

The fourth order stream is showing greater stream number then third order stream?

Comment: Did you tried remove all the values and add it again? maybe also trying to choose another color ramp

Comment: Result is incorrect, count of higher order streams must be significantly less than lower order.

Comment: But i have followed the standard procedure, level dem - agree dem - fill - fdr - fac- strdef - stream order and stream to feature.